# termios messing up stdout in terminal after exiting although old attributes are reset

Tags: c, terminal, termios

I'm using termios in a serial logging application, the application reads the serial port and saves data in a file. It also accepts inputs from standard input and sends it to the serial port.

The problem is that once the application exits (by pressing "q") the bash terminal settings are messed up and it outputs weird characters (see image)

[image: Terminal output data coming from the serial port in the middle, and when q is pressed the weird terminal behavior]

Setting the attributes back to the original succeeds with :
resultsetatr=tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&oldstdio);
and fails with :
resultsetatr=tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&oldstdio);

as shown before the program terminates.

The program is running on a Raspberrypi with USB to serial adapter.

The relevant pieces of code are :

```
     void setup_termios()
      { memset(&stdio,0,sizeof(stdio));
        stdio.c_iflag=0;
        stdio.c_oflag=0;
        stdio.c_cflag=0;
        stdio.c_lflag=0;
        stdio.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
        stdio.c_cc[VTIME]=0;

        int resultsetatr;
        resultsetatr=tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&oldstdio); //get old settings
        printf("get att stdin = %d\n",resultsetatr);
    resultsetatr=tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&stdio);
    printf("set att stdin = %d\n",resultsetatr);

        fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);       // make the reads non-blocking



    // This is the actual Serial Port termios structure
        memset(&tio,0,sizeof(tio));
        tio.c_iflag=0;
        tio.c_oflag=0;
        tio.c_cflag=CS8|CREAD|CLOCAL;           // 8n1, see termios.h for more information
        tio.c_lflag=0;
        tio.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
        tio.c_cc[VTIME]=5;

    //Opening the serial port
        tty_fd=open(DEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

        if (tty_fd < 0) {
            perror(DEVICE);
            printf("\ryou dont have permission to open serial port, use : sudo     ./seriallog\r\n");
        close(tty_fd);
        tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&oldstdio);
        exit(-1);
        }      

    cfsetospeed(&tio,BAUD);            // 9600 baud
        cfsetispeed(&tio,BAUD);            // 9600 baud

    tcgetattr(tty_fd,&oldtio); //get old settings
        tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&tio);//set to new settings
}

int main(){
    time(&t1);
    setup_termios(); 
    create_logfile();
        while (rx_char!='q')
        {
                if (read(tty_fd,&rx_char,1)>0)        
                {
                    rx_char = rx_char & 0xff;


                    //if ( rx_char < 0 || rx_char > 126) rx_char =' ';  
                    time(&t2); //take time 2
                    dt = difftime(t2,t1);
                    if (dt>1800) {tx_char ='A';write(tty_fd,&tx_char,1); t1=t2;}  
                    putc(rx_char,stdout);
                    fputc(rx_char,output_file);              
                    if (rx_char == '\r') write_date_and_time_line(1);
                    check_for_next_day_file();

                }
                if (read(STDIN_FILENO,&tx_char,1)>0)  write(tty_fd,&tx_char,1);                     

        }

        puts("\r\n");
        close(tty_fd);
        fclose(output_file);

        int resultsetatr;

        //resultsetatr=tcsetattr(tty_fd,TCSANOW,&oldtio);
        //printf("tty : %d\n\r",resultsetatr);

        resultsetatr=tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&oldstdio);
        printf("set stdin att : %d\n",resultsetatr);

        resultsetatr=tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&oldstdio);
        printf("set stdin att : %d\n",resultsetatr);



        return 0;}
```

Comment: Does it happen if you do a minimal test? i.e. just change the stdin settings, then try to set it back, without all the serial stuff?

Comment: It got even weirder for me, if i changed the log file directory from "/home/pi/...." to simply "." the problem disappears!

Comment: Sounds like you're overflowing a buffer and corrupting the termios you saved...

Comment: Calling `memset( , 0, )` and then assigning 0 to the structure elements is redundant and could cause problems. Proper practice per POSIX is to call `tcgetattr()` and then modify the individual attributes.  What's the purpose of zeroing out STDIN's attributes (you're setting the baud rate to zero)?

Comment: When a Linux system call fails and returns a `-1`, then you should retrieve and print out the global variable `errno` which will provide more detail.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, has the OP been able to fix this? I noticed that output in terminal gets back to normal after running "reset" from the command line.